# How to how check an array contains these two objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want check whether document front and back object is present in an array. If both
front and back object is present set document to true or if only front is present set document to false

```
const [document, setDocument] = useState('');

let data = [
  { id: 1, type:'document', frontBack:'front'},
  { id: 2, type:'pan', frontBack:'front'},
  { id: 3, type:'profile', frontBack:'front'},
  { id: 4, type:'document', frontBack:'back'},
];
```

Comment: you'd filter for type document then check if front and back exist

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `data` has a `frontBack:'front'` with this code:

```
data.find(({type, frontBack})=> type == 'document' && frontBack == 'front')
```

And you can check if `data` has a `frontBack:'back'` with this code:

```
data.find(({type, frontBack})=> type == 'document' && frontBack == 'back')
```

If both expressions return an object, you have both.
If any of them return `undefined`, you don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `some` method of Array object, which returns `true` if some of the elements pass the given test.

```js
let data = [{
    id: 1,
    type: 'document',
    frontBack: 'front'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: 'pan',
    frontBack: 'front'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    type: 'profile',
    frontBack: 'front'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    type: 'document',
    frontBack: 'back'
  },
];


let out = data.some(d => d.type == "document" && d.frontBack == "front") && data.some(d => d.type == "document" && d.frontBack == "back");
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches to solving this problem, but you could make use of `.some()` method to check if the criteria mentioned above are satisfied or not.

```
setDocument(data.some(item=>item.frontBack === 'front') && data.some(item=>item.frontBack === 'back'))
```

`.some()` returns true if one or more items in the iterable returns true, so we are checking if both `front` and `back` exists, and using the conditional `&&` we can say if both the items exist or not and set the state accordingly. You can also make the code more understandable by extracting the logical operation result into a separate variable, like so:

```
const res = data.some(item=>item.frontBack === 'front') && data.some(item=>item.frontBack === 'back')

setDocument(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write it out in as straightforward a way as possible. I wasn't sure which variable you meant to set, so I used one called setDoc:

```js
//const [document, setDocument] = useState('');
let data = [
    { id: 1, type:'document', frontBack:'front'},
    { id: 2, type:'pan', frontBack:'front'},
   { id: 3, type:'profile', frontBack:'front'},
   { id: 4, type:'document', frontBack:'back'},
  ];
  
let setDoc, front, back = false
data.forEach(obj => {
  if(obj.type === 'document' && obj.frontBack === 'front') {
    front = true
  }
  
  if(obj.type === 'document' && obj.frontBack === 'back') {
    back = true
  }
}) 

setDoc = front && back

console.log(setDoc)
```